# Wrapping a Model with a visual control

Tags: c#

If you have a simple data model instance.

```
class AppleModel
{
   int PipCount = 3;
   Boolean isFresh = true;
}
```

And you want to make a Visual Control of this:

```
class AppleView : PictureBox
{

    private AppleModel _model; 

    public AppleView( AppleModel model )
    {
         this._model = model;
         .........
    }

}
```

Is there a mechanism that allows AppleView to gain access to the properties of the AppleData?

For example:

```
AppleModel Model = new AppleModel();
AppleView View = new AppleView(Model);

View.PipCount = 99;
//not View.Model.PipCount = 99;
Console.WriteLine(Model.PipCount.ToString()); //99
```

Comment: Not automagically - you have to wire the relationship up yourself. I assume you know how to do that already?

Comment: Yes! From ActionScript I am familiar with manually doing this, I thought there may be a possible improvement in c#

Comment: No - and it doesn't really make much sense. Your example appears to assume that any object that composes another should be able to change its properties. I don't know of any language that allows this without manual wireup.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for [**DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx), however you're currently using winforms which does not really support that. You need to use current technology instead if you want to use modern capabilities. Have a look at [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a mechanism that allows AppleView to gain access to the
>   **properties** of the AppleData ?

Yes, those are called **Properties** in C#, an object can easily forward properties to one of its member by redeclaring them:

```
class AppleModel
{
   int PipCount { get; set; }    // Auto Property
   Boolean isFresh {get ; set; } // Auto Property
}

class AppleView : PictureBox
{

  private AppleModel _model; 

  public AppleView( AppleModel model )
  {
         this._model = model;
     .........
  }

  int PipCount 
  { 
   get { return this._model.PipCount; } 
   set { this._model.PipCount = value; }
  }

  int isFresh 
  { 
   get { return this._model.PipCount; } 
   set { this._model.PipCount = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since there appears to be no magical way to do this automatically (see comments in the main question, thanks), this is the best and only answer. Cheers Karim.